# java post to PHP with gzip using $_POST[]

Tags: java, php, json, post, gzip

hi i have the code with send post to php server but i can't get de da with the $_POST variable

in java usign gzip compress:

```
    public static void main(String[] args){

    String foo = "[{\"0\":\"12234107\",\"1\":\"2012-01-27 12:59:36.227\",\"2\":\"OXP\",\"3\":\"CUCH-93717\",\"4\":\"1\",\"5\":\"CERRADA\",\"6\":\"OXPD145\",\"7\":\"2012-01-27 13:01:09.467\",\"8\":\"UNACK_ALM\"}]";
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    GZIPOutputStream gzos = null;
    HttpClient httpclient = null;
    HttpResponse response;
    System.out.println(foo.length());
        try {

                 httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                 HttpPost httppost= new HttpPost ("http://127.0.0.1/lab/proyectos/php/java_envio_mensajes/post_json_gzip.php");
                 byte[] bgzip =  gzip(foo);
                 InputStreamEntity httpentity = new InputStreamEntity(new ByteArrayInputStream(bgzip), bgzip.length);
                 httpentity.setChunked(true);
                 httppost.setEntity(httpentity);
                 response=httpclient.execute(httppost);

                 httppost.setEntity(httpentity);

                ...
                }
}


public static byte[] gzip(String foo){
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    GZIPOutputStream gzos = null;

    try {
        gzos = new GZIPOutputStream(baos);
        gzos.write(foo.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (gzos != null) try { gzos.close(); } catch (IOException ignore) {};
    }

    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

in the php side, using gzinflate but i can't use $_POST variables like $_POST['json']

```
function logToFile($filename,$msg){
  $fd=fopen($filename,"a");
  $str="[".date("Y/m/d h:i:s")."]".$msg;
  fwrite($fd,$str."\n");
  fclose($fd);
}
$input = file_get_contents('php://input');

if(isset($input)){
$response = gzinflate(substr($input, 10)); 
logToFile("post.txt",$response);
}
```